# Testing if a web site is up by checking CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE returns 200 even if web site is false

Tags: php, curl

I'm testing this code snippet on a Windows 7 machine running EasyPHP and PHP5, when I run the code it still returns code 200, I'm using a non-existent url so it shouldn't, should it? Is this because a redirection takes place for example to http://www.123-reg.co.uk? Thats what I suspect but I am struggling to find how I get around that.

```
$url = "http://www.bnkbkvbirbcx.co.uk";
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
$hr = curl_exec($ch); 
$httpreturncode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
curl_close($ch);
echo $httpreturncode;
```

inserting var_dump($hr, curl_getinfo($ch)) produces this output;

```
string 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Fri, 28 Sep 2012 20:18:16 GMT

Server: Apache

Cache-control: no-cache, no-store

Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT

Pragma: no-cache

Connection: close

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

' (length=224)

array
'url' => string 'http://www.bnkbkvbirbcx.co.uk' (length=29)
'content_type' => string 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' (length=24)
'http_code' => int 200
'header_size' => int 224
'request_size' => int 62
'filetime' => int -1
'ssl_verify_result' => int 0
'redirect_count' => int 0
'total_time' => float 0.063
'namelookup_time' => float 0.016
'connect_time' => float 0.031
'pretransfer_time' => float 0.031
'size_upload' => float 0
'size_download' => float 0
'speed_download' => float 0
'speed_upload' => float 0
'download_content_length' => float -1
'upload_content_length' => float 0
'starttransfer_time' => float 0.063
'redirect_time' => float 0
'certinfo' => 
array
  empty
'redirect_url' => string '' (length=0)
```

Comment: I believe cURL has an option to disable redirection.

Comment: When I call a "false" site which I personally interpret as invalid page where you get an error page I'll get the response code 404 and I won't be redirected. So far I cannot see what your problem is...

Comment: You should be able to see the code now, it's only the same as in many examples so I don't know why I should have this problem.

Comment: I don't see any redirection happening from `http://www.bnkbkvbirbcx.co.uk` to `http://www.123-reg.co.uk`.

Comment: `var_dump($hr, curl_getinfo($ch));` right after `$hr = curl_exec($ch);`. Give us output. All the questions to your ISP. I cant'even find DNS records for `www.bnkbkvbirbcx.co.uk` and even `bnkbkvbirbcx.co.uk`. Looks like they realized some redirect system which automatically gives 200 answers for non-existent domains.

Comment: Is it possible my isp (virginmedia) could be managing the redirection. Am I right in thinking it is the redirection that causes the return of the success code?

Comment: Have edited the original question with the output after inserting as requested var_dump($hr, curl_getinfo($ch));

Comment: www.bnkbkvbirbcx.co.uk is totally made up, it doesnt exist, i just use it to test the code, i expect test to fail which is why I don't understand why http_code=200?

Comment: @kethi why don't you remove `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);` and add `echo $h;` to see what it returns. Some DNS servers redirects to their page in the case of invalid domains.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest to set another DNS server for your computer/server. It seems that your provider redirects non-existing domains to their homepage.

I don't know your provider virginmedia but with the german telekom there is an option to deactivate this option on their homepage.

An option would be to use an open/free DNS server like them from Google which are aviable via 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

I hope that helps!

Comment: Whatever I do  to get around this problem the fact remains that when my site goes live this URL

Comment: Sorry, will stick to the point, in a nutshell - Thank you I need to test this on a  web server not my wamp, it seems clear now that my ISP is getting in the way, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally got to the bottom of this, I feel stupid it took me so long now! My isp DOES intervene with a "handy feature" as follows: "If an address you enter doesn't locate a site, this handy feature will convert the incorrect address into a web search, so instead of an error message you will get a list of our closest matches". I also discovered I can choose to "switch off" this handy feature which I did and now I get the results I'd expect. Thanks for all your input, as you can tell from some of my shakey posts I'm new to stackoverflow but have found it good to share my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The script below might be helpful to whomever ends their search here.

The fakePhrase is used to detect ISP "Search Assist" adware HTTP responses.

```
#!/bin/bash

fakePhrase="verizon"
siteList=(
  'http://google.com'
  'https://google.com'
  'http://wikipedia.org'
  'https://wikipedia.org'
  'http://cantgettherefromhere'
  'http://searchassist.verizon.com'
)

exitStatus=0

function isUp {
  http=`curl -sL -w "%{http_code}" "$1" -o temp_isUp`
  fakeResponse=`cat temp_isUp | grep $fakePhrase`
  if [ -n "$fakeResponse" ]; then
    http=$fakePhrase
  fi
  case $http in
  [2]*)
    ;;
  [3]*)
    echo 'Redirect'
    ;;
  [4]*)
    exitStatus=4
    echo "$1 is DENIED with ${http}"
    ;;
  [5]*)
    exitStatus=5
    echo "$1 is ERROR with ${http}"
    ;;
  *)
    exitStatus=6
    echo "$1 is NO RESPONSE with ${http}"
    ;;
  esac
}

for var in "${siteList[@]}"
do
  isUp $var
done

if [ "$exitStatus" -eq "0" ]; then
  echo 'All up'
fi

rm temp_isUp
exit $exitStatus
```